# I would like to have an example of using Tensorflow ConvLSTMCell

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, sequence-to-sequence

I would like to have a small example of building an encoder-decoder network using Tensorflow ConvLSTMCell.
Thanks

Comment: Why isn't replacing GRU with ConvLSTM working?

Comment: I don't get your question @Maxim. I want to use convlstm

Comment: I mean there are lots of examples using LSTM and GRU. Have you tried to simply replace the cell in them?

Comment: @Maxim Would you please put a link to one of those examples here. I actually built a model, but the thing is with ConvLSTMCell when we have a different number of filters in each layer, the output of one layer to the next layer does not match (When I use a loop_function) in the decoder. Basically, I want to know how should I make these connections so I build a model which can predict.

Comment: Check this repo - https://github.com/maxim5/tensorflow-seq2seq-translate It's encoder-decoder network for machine translation, uses GRU cells, adapted to latest tensorflow. The main model is in `seq2seq_model.py`

Comment: It's convolutional, there could be differences. How does / does pooling happen between convLSTM cells in a multi layer network? Are there strides?